# Issue redirecting to the same page

Tags: php, loops, redirect, authentication

I'm having trouble redirecting to the same page. I keep getting the message: "The localhost page isn’t working, localhost redirected you too many times, ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS".

From my navbar there are drop downs for registering and logging in. Registering worked fine and so did the login for a few minutes then suddenly stopped working for some reason. I hadn't touched the code in over an hour.

```js
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['usr_id'])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
}

include_once 'dbconnect.php';

//set validation error flag as false
$error = false;

//check if form is submitted
if (isset($_POST['signup'])) {
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
    $cpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['cpassword']);
    
    //name can contain only alpha characters and space
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/",$name)) {
        $error = true;
        $name_error = "Name must contain only alphabets and space";
    }
    if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $error = true;
        $email_error = "Please Enter Valid Email ID";
    }
    if(strlen($password) < 6) {
        $error = true;
        $password_error = "Password must be minimum of 6 characters";
    }
    if($password != $cpassword) {
        $error = true;
        $cpassword_error = "Password and Confirm Password doesn't match";
    }
    if (!$error) {
        if(mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO users(name,email,password) VALUES('" . $name . "', '" . $email . "', '" . md5($password) . "')")) {
            $successmsg = "Successfully Registered! <a href='login.php'>Click here to Login</a>";
        } else {
            $errormsg = "Error";
        }
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '" . $email. "' and password = '" . md5($password) . "'");

    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $_SESSION['usr_id'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['usr_name'] = $row['name'];
        header("Location: index.php");
        die;
    } else {
        $errormsg = "Incorrect Email or Password!!!";
    }
}

?>
```

```html
                    <div class="wraplogin">
                        <form role="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="loginform" id="edd_login_form" class="edd_form">
                            <fieldset>
                                <legend>Log into Your Account</legend>
                                <p>
                                    <label>Username</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="email" required class="form-control" id="edd_user_login" class="required edd-input" />
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <label>Password</label>
                                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Your Password" required class="form-control" id="edd_user_pass" class="password required edd-input" />
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <input id="edd_login_submit" type="submit" class="edd_submit" name="login" value="Log In" />
                                </p>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <p class="edd-lost-password">
                                    <a href="#" title="Lost Password">Lost Password? </a>
                                </p>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                        <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($errormsg)) { echo $errormsg; } ?></span>
                    </div>
```

Anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: Code snippets are for HTML, JS and CSS only, not PHP.

Comment: If your PHP file is named `index.php`, when `isset($_SESSION['usr_id'])`, it'll keep redirecting to itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right at the beginning you do a redirect:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['usr_id'])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

However after logged in (`$_SESSION['usr_id']` is set) if this page is *index.php*, it will redirect to itself, and check again and redirect to itself, again, entering a loop

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. Thought it had something to do with session storage.